# Date merging between range and single dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset `datA` that looks as

```
ID     LINE_ID     Fromdate     Todate     UniqueID
1      1           1/1/2015     2/3/2015   11
1      2           3/7/2015     3/9/2015   12
2      1           2/2/2015     2/8/2015   21
3      1           1/3/2013     1/8/2013   31
```

And a `datB` that looks like

```
ID    LINE_ID     Date     UniqueID
1     1           1/1/2015 11
1     2           1/3/2015 12
1     3           2/2/2015 13
1     4           2/8/2015 14
1     5           3/8/2015 15
2     1           2/2/2015 21
2     2           2/3/2015 22
2     3           2/7/2015 23
2     4           2/8/2015 24
3     1           1/3/2013 31
3     2           1/7/2013 32
3     3           1/8/2013 33
3     4           1/9/2013 34
```

What I want to do is find some way to either combine both datasets or find some way to tag which `UniqueID` in `datA` belongs to what line in `datB`. For example, using the two datasets above, I would like to have `datC` look like `datB` with an added column for which `UniqueID` in `datA` corresponds.

```
ID    LINE_ID     Date     UniqueID     UniqueID.A
1     1           1/1/2015 11           11
1     2           1/3/2015 12           11
1     3           2/2/2015 13           11
1     4           2/8/2015 14           NA
1     5           3/8/2015 15           12
2     1           2/2/2015 21           21
2     2           2/3/2015 22           21
2     3           2/7/2015 23           21
2     4           2/8/2015 24           21
3     1           1/3/2013 31           31
3     2           1/7/2013 32           31
3     3           1/8/2013 33           31
3     4           1/9/2013 34           NA
```

As one can see, the new column added to `datB` is which `UniqueID` in `datA` does the date range in `datB` fall within.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to do this in R?

Comment: Many examples on SO like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491184/r-counting-dates-within-time-intervals and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807775/summing-up-values-within-an-interval-from-another-data-frame-in-r

Comment: @PierreLafortune Wow looks like I looked up the wrong thing. For a large dataset, would you recommend a `dplyr` approach or a `data.table` approach?

Comment: `data.table` . But remember to format everything correctly beforehand. Date columns are really Dates and not strings or factors, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help with the implementation. Be sure that columns are the correct types and keys are set:

```
#Create a start and end columns formatted to dates
setDT(datB)[, ':='(c("start", "end"), as.IDate(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))]

#Format columns to dates
setDT(datA)[, ':='(c("Fromdate", "Todate"), 
                   lapply(.SD, as.IDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")),
            .SDcols=c("Fromdate", "Todate")]

#Set keys for matching intervals on
setkey(datA, Fromdate, Todate)
setkey(datB, start, end)

#Match on intervals
foverlaps(datB, datA, type="within")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that you could use to merge pandas dataframes based on ranges:
https://github.com/Chrisebell24/util/blob/master/custom_merge

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def merge_range(left, right, left_val, right_low, right_high):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    left : pandas dataframe
        Left DataFrame that you are joining onto
    right : pandas dataframe
        Right DataFrame that has the ranged values
    left_val : list
        list of columns from left that contains numeric values
    right_low : list
        list of columns that you are matching to left_val
    right_high : list
        list of columns that you are matching to left_val

    Returns
    -------
    Pandas dataframe

    Example
    -------
    import numpy as np

    np.random.seed(69)
    df1, df2 = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
    df1['LETTERS'] = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f', 'g']
    df1['RAND'] = np.random.randint(1,len(df1)*10, len(df1))
    df2['COLOR'] = ['red', 'orange','yellow','green','blue','purple','brown']
    df2['LOW'] = [i*10 for i in range(0, len(df2))]
    df2['HIGH'] = [i*10 for i in range(1, 1+len(df2))]

    merge_range(df1, df2, left_val=['RAND'], right_low=['LOW'], right_high=    ['HIGH'])

        LETTERS RAND    COLOR   LOW HIGH
    0   a       55      purple  50  60
    1   b       56      purple  50  60
    2   c       21      yellow  20  30
    3   d       50      purple  50  60
    4   e       23      yellow  20  30
    5   f       10      orange  10  20
    6   g       57      purple  50  60
    '''
    true_args = True

    for lv, rl, rh in zip(left_val, right_low, right_high):
        a = left[lv].values
        bl = right[rl].values
        bh = right[rh].values

        true_args *= (a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] < bh)

    i, j = np.where(true_args)

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.column_stack([left.values[i], right.values[j]]),
        columns=left.columns.append(right.columns)
    )

    if len(df.columns) - len(set(df.columns)) > 0:
        print('Duplicate columns')

    return df
```

Comment: Mhm, I hate to disappoint you but the question asks for a solution in R.