# Match data by start and end times

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, one containing measurements and a time stamp, the other containing measurement periods with a start and end time:

```
txt1 <- "     v1     datetime
23 '2016-02-14 12:00:10'
12 '2016-02-14 12:03:10'
21 '2016-02-14 12:50:00'
52 '2016-02-14 13:01:10'
53 '2016-02-14 13:05:50'
23 '2016-02-14 13:09:25'
95 '2016-02-14 13:20:10'
11 '2016-02-14 13:21:00'
64 '2016-02-14 13:25:12'
41 '2016-02-14 13:45:34'
14 '2016-02-14 13:53:08'
"

txt2 <- "    mp     start     end
1 '2016-02-14 12:00:00' '2016-02-14 12:11:00'
2 '2016-02-14 12:58:00' '2016-02-14 13:13:00'
3 '2016-02-14 13:22:00' '2016-02-14 14:00:00'
"
d1 <- read.table(textConnection(txt1), header = TRUE,
                 colClasses = c("integer", "POSIXct"))

d2 <- read.table(textConnection(txt2), header = TRUE,
                 colClasses = c("integer", "POSIXct" ,"POSIXct"))
```

I want to assign the correct measurement period to each measurement (retaining unmatched rows):

```
"     v1     datetime     mp
23 '2016-02-14 12:00:10' 1
12 '2016-02-14 12:03:10' 1
21 '2016-02-14 12:50:00' NA
52 '2016-02-14 13:01:10' 2
53 '2016-02-14 13:05:50' 2
23 '2016-02-14 13:09:25' 2
95 '2016-02-14 13:20:10' NA
11 '2016-02-14 13:21:00' NA
64 '2016-02-14 13:25:12' 3
41 '2016-02-14 13:45:34' 3
14 '2016-02-14 13:53:08' 3
"
```

My current approach is to use a nested for loop but I am looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: try [foverlaps](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/foverlaps)?

Comment: [Date merging between range and single dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379206/date-merging-between-range-and-single-dates/38380091#38380091)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach using `sapply`. For each value in `datetime` column of `d1` we check if it falls in range of any row in `d2`. If it falls in range for `any` row then it returns the corresponding `mp` value or else returns `NA`.

```
d1$tmp <- sapply(d1$datetime, function(x) {
           mtch = x >= d2$start & x <= d2$end
           ifelse(any(mtch), d2$mp[mtch], NA)
          }) 
d1

#   v1            datetime tmp
#1  23 2016-02-14 12:00:10   1
#2  12 2016-02-14 12:03:10   1
#3  21 2016-02-14 12:50:00  NA
#4  52 2016-02-14 13:01:10   2
#5  53 2016-02-14 13:05:50   2
#6  23 2016-02-14 13:09:25   2
#7  95 2016-02-14 13:20:10  NA
#8  11 2016-02-14 13:21:00  NA
#9  64 2016-02-14 13:25:12   3
#10 41 2016-02-14 13:45:34   3
#11 14 2016-02-14 13:53:08   3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to wrap my head around how the original version of your solution (before the edit) works, how the `d2$mp` column is specified

Comment: @ringgord the original version works because you have values as 1, 2, 3 in your `mp` column, replace it with any other values and it would give you wrong values. The previous version was giving you the index position of the match using `which`, whereas what you need is the value in `mp` column which matches the index.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but the way I would do it is to first convert `d2` to a list (where each row is a list entry), and then lapply through the list to assign the proper `mp` to `d1`:

```
d1$mp <- NA
d2_list <- split(d2, seq(nrow(d2)))

lapply(
  d2_list, 
  function(row) d1$mp[d1$datetime >= row$start & d1$datetime <= row$end] <<- row$mp
)
```

Note the `<<-` assignment operator within the apply function. You will also get some print out in the console that is irrelevant, but `ds1` will be modified as intended.